# Installing Create React App with Typescript Support Via Yarn error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new Typescript/React project and am running into the following error:

```
Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error expect@29.0.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0". Got "17.4.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
`yarnpkg add @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed
Done in 25.21s.
```

To create my react project, I'm running the following command `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript` per the [Create React App docs](https://create-react-app.dev/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to not support Node 17 specifically which is what you have

Answer (score 0):

My version of node was oudated. I upgraded yarn and node using:

```
nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node

yarn install -g
```